# What is this property relating to logical systems called?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

---

**See the revised version of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420887/what-is-this-property-exhibited-by-some-logical-systems)**.

---

The following property exhibited by some logical systems has captured my attention:

$$x_1 \vdash x_2    \text{ if and only if }  \vdash (x_1 \rightarrow x_2)$$

for any well-formed formulas $x_1$ and $x_2$.

My question is 3-fold:

1. Does this property have a name? If so, what is it called?
2. Does classical *propositional* logic have this property? (I'm assuming it does, but I want to be sure.) What other systems display this property?
3. Does the presence of this property (or lack thereof) imply any other important properties about the system in question? (I realize that this third part of the question might seem overly broad, but what I really want to know is: is this property *important* and if so, *why*? Deep insights appreciated.)

EDIT: Apparently my notation for "provability" was non-standard and throwing people off (folks thought I was describing the deduction theorem), so I corrected it. Thanks @Hurkyl.

EDIT #2: Based on guidance from [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26945/how-to-properly-fix-an-embarrassing-mistake), I've reverted my corrections back to the original (wrong) notation so as not to invalidate the answers I've already received here. The [**revised version**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420887/what-is-this-property-exhibited-by-some-logical-systems) of this question with the necessary notational (and semantic) changes *has nothing to do with the deduction theorem*, as far as I know.

Comment: Hmm. Suppose $\phi \vdash \psi$ and $\vdash \phi$. Then clearly $\vdash \psi$ (just "paste" the derivation of $\psi$ into the derivation of $\phi$). On the other hand, suppose $\vdash \phi$ implies $\vdash \psi$. Can you give me an example of $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that $\phi \not \vdash \psi$ under this supposition?

Comment: What exactly is a "schema" here? You seem to be implicitly quantifying over some "instances" of $x_1$ and $x_2$, so what you really mean is $$ \forall X\; ( {\vdash x_1[X]} \implies {\vdash x_2[X]} ) \implies \forall X\; {\vdash (x_1[X]\to x_2[X])} $$ where $X$ ranges over "ways to fill in the holes in $x_1$ and $x_2$". But what counts as a hole in this context (since you're speaking about both propositional and predicate calculus)?

Comment: @Nagase Yes: see my intuitionistic logic example under "examples where this property *does not* hold".

Comment: @HenningMakholm YES!!! That is exactly what I mean. Thank you for notating that correctly for me!!! As to your question, "what counts as a hole", I am a little confused. Can you elaborate? Perhaps the "holes" in the schema have a special notation, or perhaps it would be more appropriate to think of $x_1$ and $x_2$ as *functions* rather than schemas. Does that clarify anything?

Comment: @HansBrende: As for "what counts as a hole", I'm asking: Which kinds of syntactic entities in $x_i$ can $X$ supply a replacement for? If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are functions, are they then allow to return something that they don't get from $X$? For example, if $x_1$ can be the constant function that ignores $X$ and always returns a fixed propositional variable $A$, then classical propositional logic _doesn't_ have your property.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So it would seem that every schema (function) needs to have at least one hole (arity > 0), which can't be filled by a constant, but must be enumerated over with every formula in the language that can, while preserving correctness of syntax, fill that hole. To answer your question "which kinds of syntactic entities in $x_i$ can $X$ supply a replacement for": those syntactic entities are variables (though it's possible you might be allowed to mark certain variables as "non-holes"--but I'm not sure what the implications of that would be).

Comment: @HansBrende: If you can mark propositional variables as non-holes, then $x_1[X] \equiv A_{\text{not a hole}} \land X_{\text{hole}}$ works like the example from my previous comment. Furthermore, since you also speak about predicate calculus, do (for example) predicate letters count as "variables" for this purpose? Do function letters? If so, what kind of things can you replace them with?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Predicate letters do not count as holes. If you look at my classical predicate logic example in the original question, you'll see that I'm enumerating over the "hole" $P$, not the variable $x$. I've edited that example to make it more explicit (removing the $x$ from $Px$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm due to the notational changes I made, so as not to invalidate the existing answers, I reverted my changes back to the original (incorrect) notation and created a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420887/what-is-this-property-exhibited-by-some-logical-systems). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called the [deduction-resolution property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem); it's probably best to think of it as $$\Gamma,\alpha \vdash \beta \iff \Gamma \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta.$$

Under the usual way of thinking about things, first-order logic *does* have this property, but we assume that $\alpha$ is a sentence, not just a formula.

It's worth noting the close relationship to the lattice-theoretic perspective on implication, in which the formula $$a \wedge b \leq c \iff a \leq b \rightarrow c$$ defines logical implication, also known as "relative pseudocomplements", also known as "exponential objects." See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra), for example.

Note also the connection to Cartesian closed categories, closed monoidal categories, and [closed multicategories](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.3137.pdf). The latter categorify the deduction-resolution property to give a notion of internal homs with possibly-multiple arguments.

Comment: Apologies: I may have confused a few people with the incorrect notation I was using. By $x \vdash y$, what I really meant was "$\vdash x$ implies $\vdash y$".

Comment: @HansBrende, perhaps ask a new question? This one already has answers. Or we can all just delete your answers if you want.

Comment: Due to the notational changes I made, so as not to invalidate the existing answers, I reverted my changes back to the original (incorrect) notation and created a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420887/what-is-this-property-exhibited-by-some-logical-systems). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @HansBrende, that's okay. These things happen :)

Comment: Your excellent answer to my initial question was much appreciated. Do you happen to have any insights into the revised version of my question (or an idea of where I could find the answer)?

Answer (score 3):

This is called the deduction theorem. Yes, it holds in classical propositional logic and it *does* hold in classical logic, provided that either you restrict it to conditionals with closed antecedents (thus blocking the problematic inference involving a formula with free variables in the antecedent) or you restrict the universal generalization rule (Jeffrey Ketland has some interesting remarks on the options [in this blog post](http://m-phi.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/two-notions-of-consequencededucibility.html); check out the article linked in his post).

Comment: The link to the blog post doesn't seem to work - maybe a copy/paste error?

Comment: Apologies: I may have confused a few people with the incorrect notation I was using. By $x \vdash y$, what I really meant was "$\vdash x$ implies $\vdash y$".

Comment: @psmears Fixed!

Comment: Due to the notational changes I made, so as not to invalidate the existing answers, I reverted my changes back to the original (incorrect) notation and created a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420887/what-is-this-property-exhibited-by-some-logical-systems). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it the deduction theorem, though sometimes only the first half of the 'if and only if' gets called the deduction theorem.

Yes, classical propositional logical has this property.  In Polish notation, the if part follows from the axioms CpCqp and CCpCqrCCpqCpr ('C' is the conditional), and [many other sets of axioms](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~dulrich/C-pure-intuitionism-page.htm).  It holds for any natural deduction system as well as any system that has a rule of uniform substitution, a rule of detachment, and has as axioms or theorems CpCqp and CCpCqrCCpqCpr (or their isomorphic equivalents in other notational schematics).

Yes, the presence of that property implies some other important properties... or maybe better important denials of properties.  It implies that the system is *not* a relevant logic, because no relevant logic has CpCqp (or an isomorphic equivalent) as a theorem.  Also, and I'm just figuring this out...

The property you've mentioned implies that Cpp is a theorem.  Now, assume that the operator 'C' associates.  But, CpCqp is a theorem.  So, CpCpp is a theorem.  If associativity holds and the system is sound and complete, then CCppp is a theorem also.  Since Cpp is a theorem, by detachment 'p' will then also hold.  Thus, if such a system is sound and complete, associativity will fail, since no system (with at least two truth values) is sound if 'p' is a theorem since 'p' could mean falsity.

Or in other words, the presence of soundness and completness for the system along with that property implies that the implication operator will NOT be associative.  And thus the algebraic structure of such a system cannot be that of a group or semigroup.

Comment: Apologies: I may have confused a few people with the incorrect notation I was using. By $x \vdash y$, what I really meant was "$\vdash x$ implies $\vdash y$".

Comment: @HansBrende I'm not quite sure what "implies" means in "⊢x implies ⊢y".  I mean under a usual sort of interpretation, I might paraphrase that as "if it is true that x is provable, then it is true that y is provable."  In classical propositional logic, it does hold that if $\vdash$y, then $\vdash$Cxy.  But, x is not provable and y is not provable, and $\vdash$Cxy is false (in other words, Cxy is not provable).  So, no, what you referenced doesn't hold for classical propositional logic.  I don't know of other systems that display this property either.  If I understand things correctly.

Comment: It is true that the *literal expression* $x \rightarrow y$ is not provable, but $x$ and $y$ here do not denote literal expressions. Henning Makholm puts what I am trying to say into much better notation in his comment: $\forall X\; ( {\vdash x_1[X]} \implies {\vdash x_2[X]} ) \implies \forall X\; {\vdash (x_1[X]\to x_2[X])}$

Comment: I don't follow that notation.  Nor your conversation with Henning Makholm.  I think you need more examples to make your meaning clear, at least to me.  Also, I don't know why a single variable is not an instance of x$_1$[X].

Comment: Yes, a single variable could be an instance of $x_1$. Let's use that as an example: let $x_1[P, Q] = P$ and let $x_2[P, Q] = Q$. In this case, it is *not necessarily true* that $\vdash P \implies \vdash Q$. Therefore, it doesn't matter whether or not $\vdash (P \rightarrow Q)$ is necessarily true; the whole statement is vacuously true since the antecedent is false: thus, that's not enough to state that the property does not hold.

Comment: Due to the notational changes I made, so as not to invalidate the existing answers, I reverted my changes back to the original (incorrect) notation and created a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420887/what-is-this-property-exhibited-by-some-logical-systems). Sorry for the confusion.